# Where does the manga for Beyblade original series end in comparision to the anime?

Tags: beyblade

I found on the web that there are some differences in the storyline of the manga and the anime (English) of [Beyblade (original series)](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Beyblade_%28original_series%29). In my quest to know the differences I tried to find the manga online (legal), but I've yet to know for certain how many volumes/chapters (of the manga) are available for the original Beyblade series. Wikipedia [shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade) that there are 14 issues available. But the description about Vol. 14 [here](http://www.comicvine.com/beyblade-14-vol-14/4000-261215/) is the source of confusion for me. It says:

> It's down to the final battle in the G.B.C.--the ultimate test to see which team will earn the title of Beyblade world champions! Tyson's grandfather and friends start celebrating victory before the final battle even takes place--but will the BBA Revolution actually win?

---

> I just completed the series and the aforesaid description fits into [Episode 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade_%28season_3%29) of the [Season 3 G-Revolution](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Beyblade:_G-Revolution) where BBA team stands victorious in final round of Beyblade World Championship. Also, Season 3 ran for 52 episodes and the episodes after Episode 30 dealt with a challenge named BEGA.

This is exactly my confusion. If I consider the description then it means almost 40 p.c. of anime aren't present in the last issue, Vol. 14 of manga series, and this seems to be a major difference.

Now, it all comes down to the following points:

- Am I missing something about manga of the said series?
- Could it be that the said description is incomplete or wrong?
- Where does the final issue of manga end?
- Would manga be enough to reflect the complete storyline of anime? Meaning, does there exist mini-series too?
- Optional: where can I buy/get the complete manga for the said series?

Comment: I assumed you wanted the beyblade tag but you do have the rep to [make tags](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), remember that we're still Beta so Rep levels for most privileges are actually lower that graduated sites like Stack Overflow and Arqade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Bakuden Shoot Beyblade* [manga by Aoki Takao](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Bakuten_Shoot_Beyblade_chapters) is the basis for [seasons 1 to 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_original_Beyblade_episodes) of the original anime series. Episode 51 of season 3, [*G-Revolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade_(season_3)), correlates to chapter 3 (the final chapter) of volume 14 of the manga. Chapter 3 of manga volume 14 does not correspond to *G-Revolution* episode 30.

Spoiler for final pages of manga chapter 3 and episode 51:

> Taichi and Kai stand poised to battle one more time, but the battle itself and its results are not shown. [image]

*G-Revolution* [episode 52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade_(season_3)) features

> a giant vortex crisis and then wraps up with showing images of every team and major character that appeared in the entire 3 seasons.

The contents of that episode are not covered in the manga.

Manga volume 14 includes a manga version of the *Bakuten Shoot Beyblade The Movie: Gekitou!! Takao vs. Daichi* direct-to-DVD anime film.

Volume 14 also features an epilogue one-shot manga about the children of the main characters (who are now grown up). This epilogue was not animated.

Finally, Aoki Takao commissioned novelist Tachimori Megumi to write a Bayblade *gaiden* (side story) short novel titled *Bakuden Shoot Beyblade Gaiden -Yuriy Ivanov-* for which he provided the illustration, which is [free to read on his official website](http://sakura2factory.web.fc2.com/novel.html). Fans have made an English translation of it [here](http://z4.invisionfree.com/BeyUKforum/ar/t505.htm). This novel was not animated.

There was also a spin-off manga from the original series titled [*Seidoushi BLADERS -Beyblade Battle Story-*](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Saint_Warrior_BLADERS) written by Miyazaki Masaru and illustrated by 印照 (whose *romaji* name I can't find anwhere. It might be pronounced "Shirushi Shou" or "Shirushi Teru"), collected into 3 volumes. Its content is not depicted in the anime at all.

Fans have discussed some differences between the manga and the anime in [this forum](http://z10.invisionfree.com/Beyblade_Blitzkreig/index.php?showtopic=16).

You also mentioned the English-language version of the anime. Since the English dub contains a large amount of edits from the original anime, the dub version does not match the original manga closely. You can see the dub changes from the original anime listed [here.](http://animemanga.worldbeyblade.org/index.php/Cuts_and_changes)

Comment: Exactly what I was after regarding manga! In fact that wiki link of "Cuts and Changes" is a bonus for comparison between two animes. I thought Beyblade anime (English) was good, but after reading that wiki I now see Japanese one stands higher. Thanks again.

Comment: I think a correction is needed here. I just checked Vol. 14 [here](https://archive.org/details/manga_Beyblade-v14) and none of the chapters has any content related to episodes after Episode 30 of season 3. It seems that season 3 of anime was extended beyond manga. Besides, Episode 51 is the battle between Brooklyn of BEGA and Tyson of G-Revolution team which I didn't found in Chapter 3 of Vol. 14.

Comment: @Firelord, could you tell me which episode of season 3 you think correlates to the end of chapter 3 in manga volume 14, and, for both that and for episode 51, could you tell me who is involved using their original names (since I do not keep track of any English dub names)?

Comment: I think no episode precisely correlates with Chapter 3, Vol. 14 of manga but chapter 3 is all about the final battle between Demolition boys and Team BBA for World Championship. Once can see the gist between  Episodes 25-30 of Season 3. In Episode 51, [Brooklyn](http://animemanga.worldbeyblade.org/index.php/Cuts_and_changes#Name_Changes) of Team BEGA fought against Tyson of Team G-Revolution. Nothing about BEGA is mentioned in Chapter 3, Vol. 14 of manga.